# can't select the desired ul element - CSS

Tags: html, css

Been reading and leaving out the advanced stuffs for future but this one seems to be fairly easy and straight forward but still can't get it.

```
<div class="sidenav">
        <h3>Photo Archives</h3>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="../photos.html" class="selected" >2015</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="2015.html">Singapore</a></li><li><a href="2015.html">England</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li><li><a href="2014.html">2014</a>
                </li><li><a href="2013.html">2013</a>
                </li><li><a href="2012.html">2012</a>
                </li><li><a href="2011.html">2011</a>
                </li><li><a href="2010.html">2010</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="2010.html" >Melbourne</a></li><li><a href="2010.html">Philippines</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li><li><a href="2009.html">2009</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS bit here. This one is in primary css file.

```
.sidenav {
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #c01f2c;
    text-align: center;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    }

    .sidenav h3 { padding-bottom: 15px;}
    .sidenav ul{ position:relative; }

        .sidenav ul li:hover, .selected{
            background-color: #2e2e2e; 
        }
            .sidenav ul li a {
                color:white;
                display: block;
                line-height: 3rem;
                font-size: 1.25rem;
            }

            .sidenav ul li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
            }

            .sidenav ul li ul li:hover, .selected{
                border-left: 5px solid white;
            }

            .sidenav ul ul {
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
                width: inherit;
                background-color: #c01f2c;
                padding-right: 10px;
            }

            .sidenav ul ul a {
                font-size: 1rem;
                text-align: right;
                padding-right: 10px;
```

Following CSS is exclusively for this page - 2015.html - which I have made reference to later than the main css file in the header.

```
.sidenav ul ul {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: inherit;
                background-color: #c01f2c;
                padding-right: 10px;
            }
```

**Problem** is I can't seem to select just the first ul which is first submenu with 2015.html. If I leave it as it is now, it will select both ul from 2015 and 2010. I want to select just the 2015 submenu. I've tried child, descendant, combinations all kind of selecting techniques but to no avail.

I know the thing I'm trying to do can be done with simple java but I don't want to jump to it yet. Want to keep it css and simple.

Comment: Welcome back from Code Review to SO. :) It seems that your question there has been removed successfully. Don't worry about that. If you have a concrete programming problem SO is the right place to ask. If you have a certain piece of working code and want to enhance it Code Review is your friend.

Comment: So sorry for that. This place seems to be huge. I did try finding correct community before making an account but it beat me to it. 
So that means if I have working code but need to shorten it or make it more efficient then I'm suppose to do that in Code Review?
I'll be mindful. Apologies again.

Comment: Exactly, that's what Code Review is about. And don't worry about posting something in the wrong place. It happens. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using [**`first-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-of-type), assuming 2015 is always in the first child `li` of the menu `ul`:

```
.sidenav ul li:first-of-type ul {
   // styles
}
```

> The `:first-of-type` CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of
>   its type in the list of children of its parent element.

With that said, given that the only valid children of a `ul` is `li` you can substitute with `:first-child`

Comment: I tried first-of-type on the first ul. It didn't occur to me that I need to be doing that on the li element. This worked. Thanks a lot.

Now since you've seen the li elements. How do I refer to the succeeding ones? last would be last-of type I suppose but what about the ones in between?

Comment: You can either use `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type`, or style all `li` and exclude the ones you dont need using `:not()`

Answer (score 0):

Your rule `.sidenav ul ul` targets all `ul` sub-children.

You need to use the [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-of-type) pseudo-class if you only want to target the first child

```
.sidenav ul ul:first-of-type
```

Comment: Those were the first things I tried prior to posting my question. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out ,

As you need to select the first ul in the first sub menu

```
.sidenav > ul ul:first-child {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: inherit;
                background-color: #c01f2c;
                padding-right: 10px;
            }
```

Comment: Can't remember if I tried this but it didn't work either. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

To make something dynamic use this:

```
.sidenav ul li a.selected + ul {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   width: inherit;
   background-color: #c01f2c;
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alessiozuccotti/uannpmf6/

Comment: I'm liking this place already. Haven't really used '+ combinator' a lot. Seems like I need to explore them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @СхирисхШреста the '+' selector reference the sibling of an element, read this article: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/